# Define scroll behavior in custom view (Swift + Cocoa)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview, nsscrollview

I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to create my own custom view. Here what I'm trying to do: I have an array of say, files, loaded into NSTextViews and when I scroll horizontally, I want to scroll through the files. Vertical scrolling should just scroll through the current file.

I know I how to get a scrolling text view using the storyboard, but I'm unable to create it programmatically.

I generally have a lot of difficulty finding Mac development resources, and iOS ones don't correspond well enough for me to figure things out.

(Beginner in Swift and Mac programming, but experienced in general programming)

Comment: Are you trying to use NSScrollView or are you thinking of some other mechanism?

Comment: I'm not sure what to use, but of what I read, it seems like NSScrollView is what I need. I don't know how to manipulate it correctly, though.

Comment: OK, good.  NSScrollView is far and away the best way to do this, and I was hoping you weren't trying to do this on your own.  One more question: are you using Auto Layout (constraints) or manually calculating and setting frames (springs and struts)?

Comment: I haven't yet reached that point; I'm finding it hard to find any documentation on how exactly to use it. I'm unable to even get a simple scrollable text view